# Consumir JSON desde una variable de JS

Tags: javascript, json

tengo esto

```
const productos = [
   {lenguaje: 'Ruby', año: 2005}, 
   {lenguaje: 'Javascript', año: 2001}, 
   {lenguaje: 'HTML', año: 1987}, 
   {lenguaje: 'CSS', año: 1989}, 
   {lenguaje: 'Cobol', año: 1978}, 
   {lenguaje: 'Java', año: 1969}, 
]
```

Y quiero consumir json por ejemplo

```
const productos = ALGO
```

Y así poder tener mi archivo datos.json y separarlos del código ya que serán muchos datos y así será todo más legible.

Es decir. Tengo una variable con un array (con datos dentro) y para no tener la ristra de datos dentro de mi archivo .js, quiero tener un archivo .json a parte. Para ello no se que poner a la hora de igualar la variable, como un recurso externo. Es posible esto?

Gracias.

Comment: Quieres acceder a los datos del arreglo? o quieres agregar datos a la constante productos?

Comment: Creo que lo que estas buscando es poder pasar de un string a JSON ?.. para eso javascript tienes JSON.parse()

Comment: Lo siento, creo que me explicado mal. Lo intentaré nuevamente. Tengo una variable con un array (con datos dentro) y para no tener la ristra de datos dentro de mi archivo .js, quiero tener un archivo .json a parte. Para ello no se que poner a la hora de igualar la variable, como un recurso externo. Es posible esto?

Answer (score 1):

```
const productos = [`{lenguaje: 'Ruby', año: 2005}, {lenguaje: 'Javascript', año: 2001}, {lenguaje: 'HTML', año: 1987}, {lenguaje: 'CSS', año: 1989}, {lenguaje: 'Cobol', año: 1978}, {lenguaje: 'Java', año: 1969}, ]`
```

seria algo asi para poder obtener los valores de cada uno

JS:

```
var listaproductos = [];

for(var x = 0; x < productos.length; x++) {

    var ObjectValor = new Object();

    ObjectValor.lenguaje = productos[x].lenguaje;
    ObjectValor.year = productos[x].año;

    listaproductos.push(ObjectValor);

}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se puede.

> Para hacer una petición ajax usando
>   [XMLHttpRequest()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp). Donde en el resultado de la petición será el
>   contenido de tu file.json.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "../../data/file.json", false);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ( request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
    var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(my_JSON_object);
  }
}
```

Altamente recomendable hacer el llamado asíncrono.